# Cloudinary Error: "Missing required parameter - file" via REST API

Tags: rest, cloudinary

I'm just getting started with Cloudinary, and I'm attempting to [Uploading with a direct call to the API](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_api). Using the [DHC REST Client (chrome extension)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en), I put my request together per the instructions found here at [Creating API authentication signatures](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#creating_api_authentication_signatures). Here's a screenshot of that request and response.

[image: Cloudinary Image Upload (signed)]

I also tried...

1. adding quotes around all values except timestamp as shown in the example
2. making the request a multi-part request and attaching the image to the body as a "file"
3. deleting `timestamp`, `api_key`, and `signature` and instead replacing them with `upload_preset` to try and upload an unsigned image (yes, I created the preset)
4. And finally, I did try adding `public_id` even though it says it would assign one if not provided.

In all cases, I get the same error response... `Missing required parameter - file`

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. These name/value pairs need to be added to the body of the request rather than the header. Here's what that would look like in the DHC client. Note that the upload_preset will not work for you... I only created it to test with. Also note that doing a signed request is accomplished the same way but with different parameters.

[image]